# java script radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 radio buttons from respective id's "ID1" and "ID2" for this example.
I want to have a form show when ID1 is pressed and another when ID2 is pressed (none when the user didn't select one yet).
I put display: none for both the forms in CSS and apparently the only to achieve my goal is to use js.
all I could is the following IF code but dont know how to make the result of these if and else if a function that displays block ID1 and ID2.

```js
 if (document.getElementById('student').checked) {}
 else if (document.getElementById('teacher').checked) {}
```

Comment: Please may you edit the question so the code is a runnable [mcve]? It's currently missing some HTML

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline:

```js
// Set up a click event handler on an ancestor of
// the radio buttons (<div id="wrapper"> in this
// example.
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // If it was one of the radio buttons that was clicked...
  if(event.target.classList.contains("formChooser")){
    // Hide both forms
    document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(function(f){
      f.classList.add("hidden");
    });
  
    // Show the form with the same name as the clicked radio button's value
    document.querySelector("form[name='" + 
      event.target.value + "']").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="radio" value="form1" name="form" class="formChooser"> Form 1<br>
  <input type="radio" value="form2" name="form" class="formChooser"> Form 2
</div>
<form name="form1" class="hidden">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>This is form 1</fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<form name="form2" class="hidden">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>This is form 2</fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```js
const form1 = document.querySelector("#form1");
const form2 = document.querySelector("#form2");

const firstRadio = document.querySelector("#firstRadio");
const secondRadio = document.querySelector("#secondRadio");

firstRadio.addEventListener('click', function() {
       console.log("clicked first radio");
       form1.style = "display:block;";
        });
secondRadio.addEventListener('click', function() {
       console.log("clicked second radio");
       form2.style = "display:block;";
        });
```

```html
<form id="form1" style="display:none">
<input type="text" value="text from form1">
</form>
<form id="form2" style="display:none">
<input type="text" value="text from form2">
</form>

<input type="radio" id="firstRadio">
<label for="firstRadio">First</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="secondRadio">
<label for="secondRadio">Second</label><br>
```

Comment: This solution allows both radio buttons to be selected at the same time. It also relies on inline styles and has pretty much the same event handler written twice.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be done *without* Javascript if you arrange your DOM elements the right way.

A radio button that is selected has the `:checked` pseudo-class, and that can be used in CSS.

The example below uses IDs on everything to make it simpler, but IDs are not strictly necessary, as long as you can write CSS selectors to narrowly target the elements you want.

This starts with things that are "showable" as hidden, by using `display:none`
A CSS rule that is *more specific* will override this by setting `display:block` —
    `#radio1:checked ~ #form1 { display: block; }`

The rule described in english is: when the radio-button with ID `radio1` is checked, a *sibling* (`~`) with the ID `#form1` will be set to `display:block`.

Note `~` is the [*General* sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) selector, compared to `+` which is the [*Adjacent* sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) selector. The main difference is tilde `~` works for *any* sibling, even one with other siblings in between.

```css
.showable { display: none; }
#radio1:checked ~ #form1 { display: block; }
#radio2:checked ~ #form2 { display: block; }
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio1" value="form1" name="form"> Form 1<br>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" value="form2" name="form"> Form 2

<form name="form1" id="form1" class="showable">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>This is form 1</legend>
    <label>Input One:
    <input type="text" name="field1">
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" class="showable">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>This is form 2</legend>
    <label>Input Two:
    <input type="text" name="field2">
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

For these rules to work it's important that the two radio buttons are siblings of the two forms; the radio buttons can't be enclosed in a div, such as

```
<div id="buttons">
  <input type="radio" value="form1" name="form">
  <input type="radio" value="form2" name="form">
</div>
```

because then they are no longer siblings of the forms.
(although it's possible a more complex css selector could still work(?))

Here is a complete sample page that works (for me) when served by my apache web server:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .showable { display: none; }
        #radio1:checked ~ #form1 { display: block; }
        #radio2:checked ~ #form2 { display: block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" value="form1" name="form"> Form 1<br>
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" value="form2" name="form"> Form 2

            <form name="form1" id="form1" class="showable">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>This is form 1</legend>
                <label>Input One:
                    <input type="text" name="field1">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            </form>

            <form name="form2" id="form2" class="showable">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>This is form 2</legend>
                <label>Input Two:
                    <input type="text" name="field2">
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was so sure this would work just by giving it a quick glimpse. Tried the code on the snippet and it worked like I had hoped. altered it a bit to include it in my code and it didn't work. I had tried everything before I opened a new folder, new html and css file, and copied the EXACT code, ctrl+c ctrl+v , and the page is showing me the radio buttons AND both forms no matter what.

Comment: @samervjr I don't know what to tell you. I just created (and pasted here) a complete, standalone, independent sample and it works for me.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, as I am SO embarrassed in myself. I tried the whole sample paged that you linked, and it worked. I then stupidly realized that I had not linked the html file to my css file...
It works now, thanks SO much for he help :)